# All my @FXML references are null

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, playing-cards

I'm trying to display playing cards in a FlowPane. I have a main layout and a nested layout. For some reason when I debug IntelliJ reports that all fields, on both controllers, annotated with @FXML are null.

Here's a shortened version of what I've got thus far. [Full Code on GitHub](https://github.com/frijolie/Blackjack):

#### MainWindow.fxml

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="controller.MainWindowController">
    <center>
        <fx:include fx:id="tableScene" source="TableScene.fxml"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

#### MainWindowController.java

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    MenuBar menuBar;

    @FXML
    Menu fileMenu;

    [...] more fields

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // nothing here in my code
    }

}
```

#### TableScene.fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="controller.TableSceneController">
    <children>
        <FlowPane fx:id="dealerHandFlowPane"></FlowPane>
        <FlowPane fx:id="playerHandFlowPane"></FlowPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

#### TableSceneController

```
public class TableSceneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private FlowPane dealerHandFlowPane;

    @FXML
    private FlowPane playerHandFlowPane;

    public void displayInitialHand(Player player) {
        var cards = new ArrayList<>(player.getHand().getCards());
        for (BlackjackCard card : cards) {
            if(player.getName().equals("Dealer")) {
                dealerHandFlowPane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(getCardFace(card)));
            } else {
                playerHandFlowPane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(getCardFace(card)));
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayHand(Player player) {
      var cards = new ArrayList<>(player.getHand().getCards());
    }

    public Image getCardFace(BlackjackCard card) {
        return new Image("/images/cards/" + card.getRank().getLetter()
            + card.getSuit().getLetter() + ".png");
    }

    public Image getCardBack() {
        String color[] = {"blue","red"};
        String design = "123";
        return new Image("/images/backs/" + color[0] + design.charAt(2));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // nothing here in my code either
    }

}
```

#### BlackjackMain

```
public class BlackjackMain extends Application {

    private final String MAIN_WINDOW_PATH = "/fxml/MainWindow.fxml";
    private final String ICON_PATH = "/images/blackjack_icon.png";
    private final String MAIN_STYLE_PATH = "/css/MainWindow.css";
    private final String TABLE_STYLE_PATH = "/css/TableScene.css";
    private final Image MAIN_ICON = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(ICON_PATH));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Blackjack");
        // close the app gracefully when the 'X' is clicked
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> Platform.exit());
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        initializeMainWindow(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(MAIN_ICON);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.toFront();
        initializeGame();
    }

    public void initializeMainWindow(Stage primaryStage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(MAIN_WINDOW_PATH));
        try {
          Parent mainWindow = loader.load();
          Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow,600,600);
          scene.getStylesheets().add(TABLE_STYLE_PATH);
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("There was a problem loading /fxml/MainWindow.fxml");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initializeGame() {
        var tableSceneController = new TableSceneController();
        var mainWindowController = new MainWindowController();
        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
        List<Player> allPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        var playerName = tableSceneController.getPlayerName();
        allPlayers.add(new BlackjackPlayer(playerName));
        BlackjackGame game = new BlackjackGame(dealer, allPlayers,
            mainWindowController, tableSceneController);
        game.playGame();
    }
}
```

### BlackjackGame.java

```
public class BlackjackGame implements BlackjackGameRules {

    private List<Player> playerList;
    private Deck deck;
    private Shoe shoe;
    private final TableSceneController tableSceneController;
    private final MainWindowController mainWindowController;

    public BlackjackGame(Dealer dealer, List<Player> players,
        final MainWindowController mainWindowController,
        final TableSceneController tableSceneController) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(dealer,
            "You must provide a dealer to begin the game.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(players,
            "You must provide a list of players to begin the game.");

        playerList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.tableSceneController = tableSceneController;
        this.mainWindowController = mainWindowController;

        // add dealer first for easier future access
        playerList.add(dealer);
        playerList.addAll(players);

        deck = new Deck(BlackjackGameRules.NUMBER_OF_DECKS);

        // place the shuffled deck in the shoe
        shoe = new Shoe(deck.getDeck());
    }

    public void dealInitialCards() {
        for (Player player : playerList) {
            player.getHand().addCard(shoe.dealCard());
            player.getHand().addCard(shoe.dealCard());
        }
    }

    public boolean hasValidNumberOfPlayers() {
        // this number includes the dealer
        var numPlayers = playerList.size();
        return numPlayers >= BlackjackGameRules.MIN_PLAYERS &&
            numPlayers <= BlackjackGameRules.MAX_PLAYERS;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return new ArrayList<>(playerList);
    }

    public Shoe getShoe() {
        return shoe;
    }

    public void playGame() {
        dealInitialCards();

        for(Player player: playerList) {
            tableSceneController.displayInitialHand(player);
        }

    }

}
```

I get a NullPointerException on displayIntitialHand in TableSceneController. Here's the brief stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at blackjack.controller.TableSceneController.displayInitialHand(TableSceneController.java:35)
    at blackjack.model.BlackjackGame.playGame(BlackjackGame.java:139)
    at blackjack.controller.BlackjackMain.initializeGame(BlackjackMain.java:70)
    at blackjack.controller.BlackjackMain.start(BlackjackMain.java:44)
```

For the life of me I cannot figure this one out. Where have I gone wrong? I have double checked that I've set the names of the controllers in the `fx:controller` attribues in the *.fxml files. I have also double checked that I have the `fx:id` attributes correct in the components and that they also match the `@FXML` annotations in the controller correctly.

My understanding of the process of JavaFX is:

1. that `load()` is supposed to load the *.fxml file
2. instantiate the controller (specified by the `fx:controller` attribute in the .fxml file)
3. Calls the no-arg constructor on the controller
4. Sets the @FXML values (by injection)
5. Registers any event handlers
6. Calls `initialize` on each controller

Is the problem with my nested `fxml` files? If this was the case I would think that the @FXML fields in `MainWindowController.java` would not also be `null`. I'm s truggling to figure this out. I could use another set of eyes and someone smarter than myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there exists a controller instance where the field is injected does not mean the field is injected to every single controller instance. You wouldn't expect the list created by `new ArrayList()` to contain elements simply because you added elements to some `ArrayList`...

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to figure out, but when you create the controllers for your scenes, within `initializeGame()` you do:

```
    var tableSceneController = new TableSceneController();
    var mainWindowController = new MainWindowController();
```

What this means is you are creating a new instance of the controller, not the instance that is created when you load your FXML files within `initializeMainWindow`.

To remedy this, I'd suggest creating a class variable to hold each of your controllers, and then assign them when you load the FXML files.

So, in `BlackJackMain.java`, declare class variables

```
private TableSceneController tableSceneController;
private MainWindowController mainWindowController;
```

then when you load them, I can see you load the main window in `initializeMainWindow`, so add

```
mainWindowController = loader.getController();
```

to the try block, just after the `loader.load` line.

This resolves your null pointers for this scene, but I cannot figure out where or if you load the table scene FXML, and thus you don't have an instance of the controller to pass into your method. If you do load the file, apply the same logic to it to get an instance of that controller too.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I implemented the changes you suggested, however, I'm still receiving a `NullPointeException` when I try using the class variable later in the code. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.frijolie.blackjack.controller.BlackjackMain.initializeGame(BlackjackMain.java:71)
 at com.frijolie.blackjack.controller.BlackjackMain.start(BlackjackMain.java:49)

Comment: @Frijolie i may just be blind, but in `initializeGame()`, it calls `tableScenController.getPlayerName()`, which i cannot see within the `TableSceneController` class

Comment: I think I got it worked out. I did some refactoring and removed some dependency injection from my domain objects to make the process much more simple. It appears to be working. Now to work on displaying the cards when a card is added to the List. Thanks.